# allow copy-paste between OS X and Windows VirtualBox

Tags: macos, virtualbox

Default VirtualBox keyboard configuration didn’t let me to copy-and-paste between OS X programmes and the VirtualBox VM.

Setting Shared Clipboard parameter to Bidirectional doesn't help

(Machine->Settings->General->Advanced->Shared Clipboard)

How to configure it?

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the Virtual Box Guest Additions, reboot your VM, set your Shared Clipboard, and try again. You should search for an .dmg / .iso image file called darwin. That contains the Virtual Box Guest Additions.

Comment: What version of OS X are you using on your virtual machine ?

Comment: don't forget to shut down the virtual machine and reboot your physical host computer in order changes to take effect